# Optimal solution to raise exceptions for two different data types of inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, raise

The code requires to receive two inputs from the user(one after the other). The first input is a float and the second input is an integer. I have noticed that (in my code given below) no exceptions are raised for the first input when an integer is entered. However, for second input exceptions are raised. Kindly provide a solution for the same, and I would appreciate it if you could specify the reason for the error. The code is to convert floating-point decimal to binary. You can find the entire code here: https://github.com/pbipin/floatingpointdecimaltobinary
https://pythoninsights.blogspot.com/2019/11/python-program-to-convert-floating.html

I tried placing separate exceptions for both the input. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
try:
    num = float(input('Enter a floating point decimal number: '))

except(ValueError):
    print('Please enter a valid floating point decimal')

try:
    places = int(input('Enter the number of decimal places in the result: '))

except(ValueError):
    print('Please enter a valid integer number for places')
```

```
Enter a floating point decimal number: 55
Enter the number of decimal places in the result: 4.5
Please enter a valid integer number for places
```

Comment: 55 is a valid value for a float so there is no reason for an error making this question nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to raise an exception, try this:

```
num = None
while num is None:
  try:
    num = float(input('Enter a floating point decimal number: '))
    if float(num).is_integer():
       raise ValueError('Non integers please')
  except(ValueError):
        print('Please enter a valid floating point decimal')
        num = None

places = None
while places is None: 
  try:
    places = int(input('Enter the number of decimal places in the result: '))
  except(ValueError):
    print('Please enter a valid integer number for places')
    places = None
```